# Update function doesn't work codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-update

I have this table where I have two forms to input data. At first I will input some data, then the second will update this row to input the data that was not on the first form.

I have this update model, I already made update function a few times but here I cant find the error.

Here's my model:

```
public function insert_id(){

    if('A' == NULL){
        $A = "na";
    }else{
        $A = $this->input->post('A');
    }

    if('B' == NULL){
        $B = "na";
    }else{
        $B = $this->input->post('B');
    }

    if('C' == NULL){
        $C = "na";
    }else{
        $C = $this->input->post('C');
    }

    if('D' == NULL){
        $D = "na";
    }else{
        $D = $this->input->post('D');
    }

    if('E' == NULL){
        $E = "na";
    }else{
        $E = $this->input->post('E');
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE $this->table SET A = ? , B = ? , C = ? , D = ? , E = ? WHERE ID_NUM = ?";
    $input =  array(
        'ID_NUM'    => $this->uri->segment(3),
        'A'         => $A,
        'B'     => $B,
        'C'     => $C,
        'D'         => $D,
        'E'         => $E
        );

    //print_r($input);
    //exit();

    $query =  $this->db->query($sql, $input);
    //print_r($query);
    //exit();
    return $query;

}
```

You can see I already did `print_r()` on `$input`, and it works fine, and I also did a `print_r` to `$query` and it shows `1`, so I think the code works. But when I check my database, there aren't any changes. What do you think my error is?

Comment: Binding data to query should be in same order as followed in update query just make chance to `$input` as `$input =  array($A,$B,$C,$D,$E,$this->uri->segment(3));`